# How to create typescript angle bracket on fat arrow and compare it with colon?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Here is my typescript example using a colon:

```js
interface props {
  legs: 2
};

interface body {
    head: string,
    torso: string,
    legs: number
};

const fnGetBodyUsingColon = (props: props): body => ({
  head: 'large',
  torso: 'larger',
  legs: props.legs
});
```

How can I show an example as above but using generics angle brackets?

This attempt gives me errors:

```js
const fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets<T> = (props: T): T => ({
  head: 'large',
  torso: 'larger',
  legs: props.legs
});
```

> fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets which lacks return type annotation, implicity has any return type

Comment: I think you need to write `const fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets = <T>(props: T): T => (…);`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the syntax question:

The generic type parameter is part of the call signature, not part of the variable you assign it to.  The syntax looks like this, with `<T>` moved after the `=`:

```
const identity = <T>(t: T): T => t;
```

**update**: if the above does not compile, it is because you are using .tsx files or JSX support and that confuses the parser.  See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947958/typescript-playground-error-on-using-generic-type-with-arrow-function) for more information.  To work around that, you can use a trailing comma after the type parameter declaration, like

```
const identity = <T,>(t: T): T => t;
```

---

Please note that your example code is problematic.  The compiler rightfully gives an error if you fix the syntax:

```
const fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets = <T>(props: T): T => ({
  head: 'large',
  torso: 'larger',
  legs: props.legs
}); // error!
// Type '{ head: string; torso: string; legs: any; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

That's because you are claiming that `fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets()` takes an argument of any type `T` and returns a value of the same type as the argument.  The value you're returning is almost certainly not of the same type as the argument:

```
const oops = fnGetBodyUsingAngleBrackets({ foo: "bar", baz: "qux" });
// const oops: { foo: string; baz: string; }
console.log(oops.foo.toUpperCase()); // no compiler warning; error at runtime
```

I'm not sure why exactly you want to use generics in this example so I'm not sure how to advise on how you should proceed here.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgEwKZinKBPGBeGAeAFQD4AKKALhgIEociYoBuAWACg3RJYAzMAcSRQAQiAQYAqhDhgA5gEFZAGyRCATgENgAa0EQc+YiQAOqkEYiUalujBIBvNjBgALJOoSUA5IvWqZSTwAaGEcGEFUIEC8fPyRVINDlGQsYEzMIADokiDYAX2pGGAB6Ipg401UAQjYSqgwjJBhPOxc3DxhoVWkZQqhwyMpO7sLsynUwDELcz3g9MBBYdQgpGTB1ACNlMIZ6xs8CTwy2DnBoGBB0-V4BYVEJKVkFGWU1TR0oCHsYbgvKACJ1r4-sFAQAvf4ARwArgAPP4wfIsVi1ThnC7mSgtH5RDpQLqyQpgwZ44YIk6QEDKLIgGQkdGZbEZPriIwNVQAYSWSBI1AKxVK8xgoAAtkY4MpVDAAO6+MCk8rhGDqWCqKGoODCpBAA)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont' necessarily want to use it. I'm just trying to create an example for myself to understand why I would need to use an angle bracket over just using colon.