# Typescript Playground Error on using generic type with Arrow function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

On using generic type with Arrow function, Typescript Playground throws error `Cannot find name 'T'`

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBZJcWD1RqgByCCrQaC0Ngber6UAAHhwAD4ABTwaQAK3yYk4eH4BBZBVAvPikEMqRwAEoANoAXSVIoFgpEwhwoAA3ooSiUnKh8V5JfACIIApA9GQ8LzeVaCErQABeblJIUBOkAeQknGZ1u%20qCdrqVSsUAF9gghOIIaHSGUyWWGKPoKmQ2BJPZyefyhSKzOL5lKRbL5UTlerNT6daJ9V7DcaTWaLeXrbb7d8nS6We6W9q-QxBIHg%20myOGB9ao7HgsUcM0PGQvIh4H0GMD2DQvm4zMx2AxmJB%20LBoOpEtv4HoRF4AEQAUVWDEQC30D6S2If4AcqAAcmEAA5SAJAfIIVH9L4yHeQQzy0SAjlQRwFFcaQ8FAJwNx0YYsH0FAEEQaFhEufcJE3aJdVAQx8XmRgWDYLhuCCIA)

```js
function hasAllProperties <T>(obj: any, props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T {
    return props.every((prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
}

// This throws error , wont compile 
const hasAllPropertiesArrow = <T>(obj: any, props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T => {
    return props.every((prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
}
```

As I am new to generic types , I assume its not a bug with ts playground rather my lack of understanding.
Also how can I rewrite the normal function as arrow function?

Comment: Please consult this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835492/error19-35-ts2304-cannot-find-name-t-why-i-cant-extend-interface-in-ts

Comment: Disable jsx or add a trailing comma, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41112313/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a design limitation of the TypeScript *parser*; see [microsoft/TypeScript#15713](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15713) for an authoritative answer.  The syntax `const x = <T>()` fools the compiler into thinking that `<T>` is a [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) tag; you can verify this by looking at the rest of the error message, which says something like `JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag.`

If you don't need JSX/TSX support you can remove [the `--jsx` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx) setting as in [this Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgBYEMDOBBANrgBQCcEAHAUyPnM2QB4AVAPgAoEAjAKwC5l0IAngBpkpEqUy8WAa3ICEIZAwCUAbQC6y3h07I4tBsgDewZGeRFyMMERRiymAHTkAbpQEsW90suQBeJmQdRwxMAHkAdwhiMkoYD29lZWAAX2BgKCRMGDQsPEJxOLgabCISCP96ZjYuXn5hUXFJZBk5BSU1TW0uPQN-QJNzCysbOybnNyIPL3FfAKCuEKxI6MKqBNnktPSgA).  If you *do* need JSX support then you can work around this by using a trailing comma after the introduction of the `T` type parameter:

```
const hasAllPropertiesArrow = <T,>(obj: any, props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T => {
    return props.every((prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
}
```

This comma has no effect on the meaning of the code but it stops the parser from getting confused.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgBYEMDOBBANrgBQCcEAHAUyPnMwB4AVAPgAoEAjAKwC5l0IBPADTJSJUph7MA1uX4IQyegEoA2gF0lPdh2RxMi5AG9gyU8iLkYYIilFlMAOnIA3Sv2bM7pJcgC8jZG0HDEwAeQB3CGIyShh3LyUlYABfYGAoJEwYNCw8QjFYuBpsIhJwv2QGQRZtHj4hETEJZGlZeUVVDS1OXX16PwDjM3NLa1smp1cid08xH39AzmCsCKiCqni5pNS0oA)